# Neo4j & Neography - get cypher query results in a hash / openstruct object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j, neography

I'm using the awesome neography gem and have run into a slight problem converting the results of a Cypher query to a structured object (OpenStruct.new... )

I don't know how to create a hash or a OpenStruct from the columns and data query results, which are

```
{"columns"=>["p.pd_challenge_id", "p.author_id"], "data"=>[["158", "88"], ["158", "90"], ["158", "99"], ["158", "95"], ["158", "97"]]}
```

I cannot create a usable hash from it. .I've tried several things including

```
["data"].map{|x|{ "challenge_id" => x[1],"author_id"=>x[0]}}.to_json
```

results in

```
{{"challenge_id":158, "author_id":88}, {"challenge_id":158, "author_id":90}, {"challenge_id":158, "author_id":99}}    etc..   (to which I simply cannot convert to a hash or openstruct)
```

What I'm looking for is for something like the following stored in a struct object so the scaffolded view can read it unmodified:

```
{:challenge_id=>158, :author_id=>88}
{:challenge_id=>158, :author_id=>90}
{:challenge_id=>158, :author_id=>99}
```

**my view would look for  object.challenge_id**

Now, I've tried to use to_sym on "challenge_id" to no avail while using .map method..

I've tried to Hash[@mydata] on ["data"] which also does not work

Is there a simple way to get all of this data into a structured object (OpenStruct.new .. ) so that my forms can simply read it as if it were reading the results of an active record query?  I can do this with neo.get_node_properties but just can't seem to get this working right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's say you have two nodes, with a name and title.

```
cypher = "start n = node(1,2) return n.name as name, n.title as title"
results = @neo.execute_query(cypher)
{"columns"=>["name", "title"], "data"=>[["Marc", "awesome"], ["Tom", "chief"]]}
```

Then you take your results and do this:

```
array_of_hashes = results["data"].map {|row| Hash[*results["columns"].zip(row).flatten] }
```

Which will leave you with :

`[{"name"=>"Marc", "title"=>"awesome"}, {"name"=>"Tom", "title"=>"chief"}]`

You can stop here or...

`objects = array_of_hashes.map{|m| OpenStruct.new(m)}`

`[#<OpenStruct name="Marc", title="awesome">, #<OpenStruct name="Tom", title="chief">]`

Which you can then access

`objects.first.name`
 => "Marc"

Comment: Max - this is a great answer, but what about null values? When the data contains them, the resulting struct is not out of alignment - data is in the wrong columns.. Any way to preserve null values?